MAC How to make Midnight Commander look like it does unde VS Code?
I am on Mac OS, using Midnight Commander and I'm loving it. I really like that I can even use it under VS Code. Look at this beauty:
MC in VS Code terminal
But when I use it directly in the terminal this is what I get:
MC in Mac OS terminal
I like the VS Code terminal presentation better.
Is there a way to make the VS Code presentation the default for the terminal?

Is it mostly the color scheme, or do you have some other differences in mind?

(I'd probably suggest just using VSCode as your terminal – there was a shortcut to open it in a new standalone tab like a document, not just the mini-terminal at the bottom.)

Just the colour scheme.

Thank you I am going to research how to do that
